# Is there a Mach band on a step edge or not?

Tags: perception, vision, optical-illusion

Recently, I've been reading about the Mach band effect and there is a particular case which is confusing me a little bit, since people don't seem to agree on what actually should be perceived.

It is the scenario where you have a step-function luminance profile, i.e. an abrupt transition between two (distinct) regions of constant brightness, resulting in a sharp edge. In [this paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnhum.2014.00843/full), the author explicitly states that "*there are no Mach bands at a step edge*", however, [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6366/c489d6dc2bac4145a1715554bbf7f670849a.pdf) it is said that "*just like the Mach
bands in vision, the undershoot and overshoot depend on the change in the
gradient of the stimulus distribution. The undershoot and overshoot
reach their maximum for a step function.*" Well, which way it is then?

Although I understand [this argument here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0042698984901020), I do actually see an (apparent) brightness decay/rise in [these stripes](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/Bandes_de_mach.PNG/220px-Bandes_de_mach.PNG), near the edges, which are essentially just a series of step-functions.